# Multiple range by python list in simple way

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a=[34,567,87]
w=67



 [ (1 / (1 + w)) ** i for i in range (1,6)]
```

which works good as w in this case is int.

But instead I want replace w by list a. It gives an awkward output- so it is incorrect.

How to multiple list by range to get the correct value. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: By *awkward output* you mean exception? what exactly are you trying to do? what is the expected output?

Comment: I want to multiply list of values by range

Comment: Please clarify your desired output. None of ``1 + <list>``, ``1/<list>``, or ``<list> ** 1`` is well-defined in Python. What do you mean by "multiple list by range" or "multiply list of values by range"? These are different things, and different from what your code is doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a=[34,567,87]
w=67

[ (1 / (1 + w)) ** i for w in a for i in range (1,6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use a nested list comprehension. Using for example:

```
a = [34,567,87]
w = a[:]

[[(1 / (1 + j)) ** i  for j in w] for i in range (1,6)]

[[0.02857142857142857, 0.0017605633802816902, 0.011363636363636364],
 [0.0008163265306122448, 3.099583415988891e-06, 0.00012913223140495868],
 [2.332361516034985e-05, 5.457013056318471e-09, 1.4674117205108941e-06],
 [6.663890045814243e-07, 9.607417352673364e-12, 1.6675133187623798e-08],
 [1.9039685845183553e-08, 1.6914467170199584e-14, 1.8949014985936134e-10]]
```

Though I'd suggest using numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([34,567,87])
w = np.copy(a)

(1 / (1 + w)) ** np.arange(1,6)[:,None]

array([[2.85714286e-02, 1.76056338e-03, 1.13636364e-02],
       [8.16326531e-04, 3.09958342e-06, 1.29132231e-04],
       [2.33236152e-05, 5.45701306e-09, 1.46741172e-06],
       [6.66389005e-07, 9.60741735e-12, 1.66751332e-08],
       [1.90396858e-08, 1.69144672e-14, 1.89490150e-10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use element-wise operators (here with numpy):

```
[ numpy.divide(1,numpy.add(1,a)) ** i for i in range (1,6)]
```